# Geometry Nodes - Reverse curves according to endpoint position

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

This feels like it should be possible but I just can't get it to work - what I want is to be able to break a number of curves in two at some position where they intersect a "Collision" mesh and then reverse the curves whose endpoints are not end point closest to the breaking point. That way the curves when trimmed or vector rotated will all trim or curl up *away* from the breaking point.

I keep trying to:

1. Store the position where the collision mesh overlaps with the curves.
2. Store the position where the new curve endpoints are.
3. Reverse the curves whose distance is greater than some nominal amount.

But I can't get it to work. Presumably because I don't know how to apply the endpoint data to the splines to select the ones for the reversal. But it has to be possible, right?

I could probably divide the mesh in some other way - reverse the curves who lie one or the other side of the collision object. But this seems way less versatile and will end up needing all sorts of band aids/other solutions for situations where the collision mesh isn't basically planar and doesn't lie neatly along an axis.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed the nodes:

[image]

First, you have to store the position of first point into splines instead of points like this:

[image]

Second, use the position of first point to find the closest point on the surface:

[image]

Evaluate on domain seems to be useless

[image]

And btw, remove unnecessary data from file before upload, there are 3 move clips in your file.

Comment: Thank you so so much!